# Position div off screen to the top and only show specific height of bottom portion of the div

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design

Is there any CSS only solution to position a **dynamic height** div off the screen to the top and only show a **fixed height** bottom portion of it on the screen?

See image for a clear explanation: [image]

I know this can be done using javascript by simply getting the height of the div and then setting the "top" property to negative height of the div + the height of the portion to be visible, but I am looking for a non JS solution.

Comment: Are you wanting a certain % of it hidden or a certain px value hidden?

Comment: The height of the hidden portion will vary depending on the screen size, the bottom visible portion is to be fixed, 100px for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to leave a certain percentage of the screen visible, then you can manipulate the `bottom` of hidden container:

```css
.hidden {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 95%; /* Leave 5% across top */
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="hidden">
    Header<br/>
    Header<br/>
    Header<br/>
    Header
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Close, but what if I wanted the visible portion to be a fixed height and not a percentage?

Comment: I don't imagine that's possible in pure css with dynamic height.